# Sorting a set of integer IDs alphabetically by value in redis

Tags: redis

I am using redis as a data store for a web application.  The basic design is built on hashes for objects and zsets for indexes, e.g.

```
user:<USER_ID> => hash(username: STRING, user_id: INTEGER, last_visit_date: FLOAT, create_date: FLOAT)
users:by_last_visit => zset( (last_visit_date, user_id) ...)
users:by_create_date => zset( (create_date, user_id) ... )
```

where my dates are stored as seconds since epoch.  This has worked very well up to this point - I can use the powerful zset operations to quickly get relevant ranges, do pagination, etc. and my ordering requirements map naturally to the floating point space.

Now, however, I have a requirement to sort alphabetically.  I know that a zset will sort alphabetically by value to break a tie on score.  My best solution so far is to put my strings in as values with a score of zero, and rely on this feature.  I don't like this because I end up with some sets having IDs as values and some sets having strings as values - I need application logic to figure out which type of set it's using at a given time and map the strings back to IDs.  Also, I lose the ability to union/intersect my sets at will.

My next best solution is to map the strings to floating point scores, but that seems very messy and error prone, as the strings can be arbitrarily long.

Is there a better option than throwing the strings into a zset all with the same score and maintaining a reverse map back to the ids?  Presuming that is the best solution, is it reliable (i.e. am I relying on a side effect or a real feature)?

Comment: re. mapping strings to scores - that approach has been discussed a few times on the redis mailing list. Search the archives or send an email to the group - you will very likely get some ideas